# Appointment for interview inquiry

Tags: interviewing

I have an upcoming interview for a cto discuss to me verbally by the interviewer last week after the interview and he told me to notify me this week but unfortunately i email and sms and email the  management regarding this but unfortunately no response. Tomorrow i will have an interview 3 blocks away from their office and its a different company. May i know if its ok or good to visit them to ask regarding my schedule ?

Comment: Have you considered calling them?

Comment: It is not very clear, what you have done with the company you are interested in.

Comment: email and sms are very impersonal ways to contact for a high level job like CTO (I am assuming you are going for a CTO position) and they are very easy to miss, especially if the recipient(s) have busy mailbox(es). Why don't you call the person who facilitated/scheduled your interview and start from that point ?

Answer (score 1):

Visiting comes across as pretty forward,  it would fit if the company is very informal but not really be appropriate otherwise. As the others said, I think a phone call is the way to go